# Galois cohomology of the Serre group in the proof of the fundamental theorem of CM

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, galois-cohomology, complex-multiplication

I am working through J.S. Milne's [note](http://www.jmilne.org/math/articles/1981dT.pdf) on the fundamental theorem of complex multiplication over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Let $E$ be a CM-field Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $S^E$ the Serre group corresponding to $E$.   One key step of the proof is to construct a map $e: Aut(\mathbb{C})\to  S^E(\mathbb{A}_{f, \mathbb{Q}})/S^E(\mathbb{Q})$ with certain universal properties (and show that it is trivial in the end). The map $e$ is first constructed as a map $e: Aut(\mathbb{C})\to  S^E(\mathbb{A}_{f, E})/S^E(E)$ whose image is fixed by $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$. Then one needs to show that its image actually lies in $S^E(\mathbb{A}_{f, \mathbb{Q}})/S^E(\mathbb{Q})$, and this is where I am getting stuck.

In the proof of Proposition 8.5, we have an exact sequence $$0\to S^E(\mathbb{Q})\to S^E(\mathbb{A}_{f,\mathbb{Q}})\to (S^E(\mathbb{A}_{f, E})/S^E(E))^{Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})}\to H^1(\mathbb{Q}, S^E),$$
and need to show that the image of $e(\tau)$ in $H^1(\mathbb{Q}, S^E)$ is zero for all $\tau\in Aut(\mathbb{C})$. The note says

> But $H^1(\mathbb{Q}, S^E)\hookrightarrow \prod_{\ell, \infty} H^1(\mathbb{Q}, S^E)$, as follows easily from (4.1), and the image of $e(\tau)$ in $H^1(\mathbb{Q}_\ell, S^E)$ is obvious zero for all finite $\ell$.

The local-global principle part of the statement is clear, but I couldn't figure out why the image of $e(\tau)$ in $H^1(\mathbb{Q}_\ell, S^E)$ is zero for finite $\ell$.